# How to identify the serial console port pads on device

Tags: pcb, uart, serial

I want to identify the serial console port pads on the board. The place for male header connector(yellow arrow) have 6 pads. Usually it’s not difficult to identify Rx, Tx, GND pins with a multimeter, but here I'm not sure about the purpose of 4-pin square connector on the half of connector. There are two square pads to indicate pin number 1, so it looks like there are two different conectors combined within one header. Can anybody clarify this?

[image: console port]

Comment: It could be a million different things. Best bet is to probe them with a multimeter first to get an idea what is going on, then a 'scope, then a logic probe. Could be a JTAG header or similar also. What chip are these going to? Identify the pins, coorelate them to a function.

Comment: Looks to me like 2 different connector footprints for the same function - one overlayed on top of the other. I suspect that the 2 pins on the left are connected to the other 2 pins on the bottom.

Comment: Broadcom BCM3382 MIPS SoC. I would exclude the JTAG header here, as cpu is MIPS, and usually have at least 8 pins.

Comment: I tested with a multimeter: pin 2 on the left and pin 3 on the right side are GND. The voltage on the other pins is 3.27V

Comment: @rdtsc If to use scope, what is common signal waveform shapes at UART interface 3.3v: Rx, Tx and VCC pins? Is it possible to distinguish by waveform shape which signal belongs to Rx, Tx, and VCC?

Comment: If it is [serial TTL](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/215) 3.3v, the TX pin will usually be high but pulse low when SoC transmits data (which it might not do without you sending it a valid command first, if transmit is enabled at all.) The RX pin may be low via a pull-down resistor but can be pulled up fairly easily, say by a 1k resistor. If you find the RX pin, then you need to figure out what baud rate, parity, and other settings it wants.